# Matlab AR digital fiter computation w/o loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, filtering

I'm given the a(k) matrix and e(n) and I need to compute y(n) from the following eq:

```
y(n) = sum(k = 1 to 10 )( a(k)*y(n-k) ) + e(n).
```

I have the a matrix(filter coefficients) and the e matrix (the residual), therefore there is only 1 unknown: y, which is built by the previous 10 samples of y.

**An example to this equation:**

say e(0) (my first residual sample) = 3

and y(-10) to y(-1) = 0 
then y(0), my first sample in the signal y, would just be e(0) = 3:

```
y(0) =  a(1)*y(-1) + a(2)*y(-2) + .... + a(10)*y(-10) + e(0) = e(0) = 3
```

and if e(1) = 4, and a(1) = 5, then

```
y(1) = a(1)*y(0) + a(2)*y(-1) + a(3)&y(-2) + ... + a(10)*y(-9) + e(1) = 19
```

**The problem is**

I don't know how to do this without loops because, say, y(n) needs y(n-1), so I need to immediately append y(n-1) into my matrix in order to get y(n).

If n (the number of samples) = say, 10,000,000, then using a loop is not ideal.

**What I've done so far**

I have not implemented anything. The only thing I've done for this particular problem is research on what kind of Matlab functions I could use.

**What I need**

A Matlab function that, given an equation and or input matrix, computes the next y(n) and automatically appends that to the input matrix, and then computes the next y(n+1), and automatically append that to the input matrix and so on.

**If there is anything regarding my approach**

That seems like it's on the wrong track, or my question isn't clear enough, of if there is no such matlab function that exists, then I apologize in advance. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please read [ask], let us see what you have implemented so far and append a minimal example with the desired input/ output

Comment: Question has been edited.